# TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) in numba

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to write my first function for parallelization

But the problem is, that I get the following error:

```
possible_EVENTS = np.array([""])
@njit(parallel=True,nopython=True)
def add_History(events,EVENTS):
    index=events.where(events=="Repair")
    add=np.array("")
    pre_events=events[index:]
    if ("LOMT" in pre_events) & ("DIMT" in pre_events):
        for i in pre_events:
            if "FU" not in i:
                add.append(i)
            else:
                break
    if len(add)>=5:
        possible_EVENTS .append(add)

for i in tqdm(packages):
    events=np.array(df_["Event"].loc[df_["Packages"]==i].values)
    add_History(events,possible_EVENTS )
```

But I get this error.

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\local_PIETAPA\Temp\ipykernel_16492\3239905456.py in <module>
     16 for container in tqdm(container_search):
     17     events=np.array(df_["EVENT_CODE"].loc[df_["UNIT"]==container].values)
---> 18     add_EPOS_History(events,EPOS_EVENTS)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    466                 e.patch_message(msg)
    467 
--> 468             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407                 raise e
    408             else:
--> 409                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
    410 
    411         argtypes = []

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
During: typing of argument at C:\Users\local_PIETAPA\Temp\ipykernel_16492\3239905456.py (4)

File "..\..\..\local_PIETAPA\Temp\ipykernel_16492\3239905456.py", line 4:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

And I have no idea how to fix it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Numba complains because you are providing it **dynamic Python object** which are **not supported by Numba** (and cannot be efficiently supported by any similar tools). This is certainly because `events` is an array of object and not an array of string. You need to **ensure the input dtype is of type string**, not object.

There are many other issues in the code:

- Note that strings are not yet efficiently supported by Numba.
- Also please note that `parallel=True` will not automagically parallelise your function. You need to use `prange` for that and check it can work (ie. it not introduces bugs like race conditions). The thing is you cannot easily use `prange` here because of the `append` so `parallel=True` is currently useless.
- Using `add.append(i)` is a bad idea here since `add` is a Numpy array. Doing that cause the execution time to be quadratic instead of linear because new array is created every time the function is called. This is a common issue. The solution is to append the items to a list and then convert the list to a Numpy array.
- Global arrays are assumed to be constant. You should not modify them (this is a very bad in software engineering anyway). The solution is to provide the array to the function and return the you one. Indeed, `append` creates a new array, it does not modify the current array. I strongly advise you to *carefully* read the documentation of [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). In the end, **your current function compute nothing, even without Numba! Please check your code before trying to make it faster**.
- `events.where(events=="Repair")` travel the whole `events` array which is less efficient than iterating over the array and break when the item location is found.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is related to the use of possible_EVENTS. It is defined as a numpy array with a single string element, [""]. However, in the add_History function, you are trying to append to this array, which is not possible with numpy arrays.

You can resolve this issue by converting the numpy array to a Python list, appending the elements to the list, and converting the list back to a numpy array.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

possible_EVENTS = [""]

@njit(parallel=True,nopython=True)
def add_History(events,EVENTS):
    index=events.where(events=="Repair")
    add=[]
    pre_events=events[index:]
    if ("LOMT" in pre_events) & ("DIMT" in pre_events):
        for i in pre_events:
            if "FU" not in i:
                add.append(i)
            else:
                break
    if len(add)>=5:
        possible_EVENTS.append(add)

for i in tqdm(packages):
    events=np.array(df_["Event"].loc[df_["Packages"]==i].values)
    add_History(events,possible_EVENTS)
possible_EVENTS = np.array(possible_EVENTS)
```

Note that using the njit decorator with parallel=True may not always result in faster execution, and it is recommended to test the performance with and without parallelization to determine the best approach.

Comment: No, this does *not* work. Please try to run it. Numba cannot operate on a reflected lists in `njit` mode: this is not supported, especially for global that are assumed to be constants anyway. Besides, the statement "*you are trying to append to this array, which is not possible with numpy arrays*" is also rather wrong: `np.append` does that though it does not operate in place like most Numpy operations. Numpy array in-place appending is possible but tricky and bug-prone since it can only be done using low-level unsafe operations.